# Hibernate @UpdateTimestamp annotation usage

Tags: java, hibernate

I am using Hibernate core 5.4.22 and Hibernate common annotations 5.1.2. I have tried to save the update timestamp on the DB entry using the following annotation:

```java
@UpdateTimestamp
private LocalDateTime closedDateTime;
```

Unfortunately, this works only when creating a new entry in the DB but not when updating the entry row.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

According to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#mapping-generated-UpdateTimestamp):

> The `@UpdateTimestamp` annotation instructs Hibernate to set the annotated entity attribute with the current timestamp value of the JVM *when the entity is being persisted.*
>
> The supported property types are:
>
> - java.util.Date
> - java.util.Calendar
> - java.sql.Date
> - java.sql.Time
> - java.sql.Timestamp

You use direct update query, but the `@UpdateTimestamp` annotation does not work for this case.

Imagine you have the `TestData` entity:

```java
@Entity
public class TestData
{
   @Id
   private Long id;

   private String name;

   @UpdateTimestamp
   private LocalDateTime time;
}
```

So, you can create new entity in the following way:

```java
TestData testData = new TestData();
testData.setId(1L);
testData.setName("Name 1");
entityManager.persist(testData);
```

or update existing entity in the following way:

```java
TestData testData = entityManager.find(TestData.class, 1L);
testData.setName("Name 11");
testData = entityManager.merge(testData);
```

in the last case hibernate will update the `time` field automatically by the following query:

```sql
13:00:32,468 DEBUG SQL:144 - // update com.test.hibernate.entities.TestData 
update  TEST_SCHEMA.TST_TEST_DATA 
set
   name=?,
   time=? 
where
   id=?
```

Comment: well, I have changed to java.sql.Timestamp; but it seems that update timestamp get inserted only during insertion in the DB not during the Update statement

Comment: I have tested timestamp update with hibernate core 5.4.22 and it works fine (by the way it also works with `LocalDateTime` java type) so it looks like your problem lies in other place. What database do you use? What database type do you use for the column? What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: And could you also provide code snippet how you update your entity.

Comment: dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect, column type: datetime

Comment: `String updateTicketStatus = "UPDATE Ticket T set T.Etat= :etat WHERE ticket_id= :ticketId";
  Query query = session.createQuery(updateTicketStatus);
  query.setParameter("etat", ticket.getEtat());
  query.setParameter("ticketId", ticket.getTicket_id());
  query.executeUpdate();
  // commit transaction
  transaction.commit();`

Comment: but still get the columns annotated with `@UpdateTimestamp` initialized with same date as `@CreationTimestamp` when saving a new Entity to the database with: `em.getTransaction().begin(); em.persist(ticket);em.getTransaction().commit();`